# Degree of Parallelism in oracle index affects the DB load

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle11g

I have 4 DB RAC's in a server.
Executing a query on a particular index causes huge load and affects the other RAC's as well. PFB the degree of the index,

- DEGREE : 10
- INSTANCES : 1

Will decreasing the degree of this index fix the problem? Please advice!

Comment: that means the query is being executed 10 times on the sever so thats will require more cpu usage which means it will have affect on RAC. my question this query how much time is taking to finish ? is it reading the right index ? the table containes lot of records ?

Answer (score 0):

Without having all the details about your case, my guess would be that you have AMM (Automatic Memory Management) disabled. With AMM disabled, parallel queries cause stress on your Shared Pool which can noticeably stall other queries, whereas the amount of stress grows exponentially (example: parallel 2 might be fine while parallel 90 might stall all nodes for 10 seconds each time the parallel 90 query is started). So based on the limited knowledge of your problem, my first two suggestions would be to check whether you have AMM on. If not, either switch it on, or try to reduce the parallelism of your queries to e.g. 4. PS: Parallelism of statistic gathering is sometimes overlooked as a source of parallel queries in great numbers with high parallelism. HTH